# INTERSECT NOT WORKING

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing a mysql query in the php-mysql framework which involved intersection of the results of 2 queries. But it is not executing. Maybe the syntax for the INTERSECT operations needs to be changed. Can you tell me where is the mistake?

```
SELECT p.*
FROM property p
    , property_type pt
    , location l
    , city c
WHERE p.STATUS = 1
    AND p.prop_id = '1'
    AND p.property_type = 'Sale'
    AND (
        pt.prop_name LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR p.furnish LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR p.description LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR p.bed LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR p.term_condition LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR p.bedroom LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR p.property_type LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR c.city_name LIKE '%dlf%'
        OR (
            (
                p.location_id = l.loct_id
                AND l.loct_name LIKE '%dlf%'
                )
            )
        )
    AND p.prop_id = pt.prop_id
    AND p.city = c.city_id

INTERSECT

SELECT p.*
FROM property p
    , property_type pt
    , location l
    , city c
WHERE p.STATUS = 1
    AND p.prop_id = '1'
    AND p.property_type = 'Sale'
    AND (
        pt.prop_name LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR p.furnish LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR p.description LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR p.bed LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR p.term_condition LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR p.bedroom LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR p.property_type LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR c.city_name LIKE '%sohna%'
        OR (
            (
                p.location_id = l.loct_id
                AND l.loct_name LIKE '%sohna%'
                )
            )
        )
    AND p.prop_id = pt.prop_id
    AND p.city = c.city_id
ORDER BY sortnum LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But it is showing the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'intersect Select p.* from property p,property_type pt,location l,city c where p.' at line 1
```

Can you let me know what would be the proper syntax?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support `INTERSECT`, use a `WHERE` or `JOIN` instead. Take a look at http://gablog.eu/online/node/33 for a solution.